# listElement property not behaving as expected

Tags: fine-uploader

Hi have created a JSFiddle of my problem here.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7o1nct6/2/

I will also repeat the code here as Stackoverflow is forcing me to do.

JavaScript

```
        <!-- using fine uploader 5.1.3 at http://keysymmetrics.com/jsfiddle/jquery.fine-uploader.js -->

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
            listElement: $('#listElement'),
            debug: true,
            template: 'qq-template-bootstrap',
            request: {
                endpoint: "/my-endpoint"
            }

        });

    });
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-bootstrap" class="qq-uploader-selector">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" >
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector
                            qq-upload-drop-area-selector
                            drag-drop-area" >
            <div>Drag and drop files here or click to upload</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<div class="qq-upload-list-selector" id="#listElement" >
    <div class="panel panel-default" >
        <div class="panel-body" >
            <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector progress">
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
            <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
            <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
            <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" />
        </div><!-- close panel-body -->
    </div><!-- close panel -->
</div>

</script>
<h1>Fine Uploader Test</h1>
<div id="fine-uploader"></div>
```

When viewing the JSFiddle example, if you open the debug console, you will see the message "Uncaught Error: Could not find the file list container in the template!".

I am unsure what this means, I thought I could use the listElement property to tell fine-uploader which element to use for this list?

On a side note, if I cut and paste the div with id=listElement and move it adjacent to the div with class=qq-upload-button-selector then this example works fine.

Any help would be appreciated, I have spent hours on this and haven't found an answer for this on stackoverflow either.

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues with your code:

1. "#listelement" is not a valid html element ID in all browsers.
2. You are attempting to select an element that does not yet exist in the DOM.  It's not clear why you are specifying a list element anyway.  Fine uploader should find the list in the template when it renders.

Comment: In response to point 1, am now using a valid element ID of "list-element", I have also moved the "list-element" div out of the script tag and into the main HTML body. You can see the corrected versions here http://jsfiddle.net/L7o1nct6/4/ . however I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: In response to point 2, I have created a working version which is not even using the listElement property here http://jsfiddle.net/61motjed/2/ (Works fine). However, please see this slightly modified version here with the "qq-upload-list-selector" is a different position in the dom, http://jsfiddle.net/Lu82ba9L/1/ . You will see that this version is getting the original error.

Comment: Please create a new version with your new question. Please do not "fix" your code in response to an answer, or ask follow-up questions as comments.

Comment: thanks for the advice on my stackoverflow etiquette. I have asked the follow up question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985828/could-not-find-the-file-list-container-in-the-template-error